# Overwrote /dev/sda with mv command

Tags: hard-drive, overwrite

I made an error while writing my command too fast and "overwrote"(?) `/dev/sda` instead of moving a file in `/dev` directory. How can I recover it?

Also what exactly is `/dev/sda`? Is it the directory where the hard drive/SSD is mounted?

Comment: Rebooting will recover all your /dev files. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18423187/7544655) answer on stackoverflow    explains a lot about device files.

Comment: You mean you ran `mv somefile /dev/sda`? I would assume it works similarly as `cp`, that is, the beginning part of your disk is overwritten with the data of that file. The data that are orignally on that part of the disk would be the MBR, partition table, and maybe part of filesystem on the first partition, and maybe more. It depends on how large was that file you moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do (with regular files):

```
echo 1 > source
echo 2 > target
cp -l target target2
mv source target
cat target2
```

then I get `2`. This means nothing is written to the `target`, it's just unlinked before `source` gets renamed, I think. With `ls -i -1` I can check that `source` keeps its inode number even if `target` existed before.

Another test is

```
mv /dev/urandom /dev/sr0
```

It doesn't send data to my optical drive. Instead, after that `/dev/sr0` behaves as `/dev/urandom`.

**The conclusion is:** your `/dev/sda` was replaced by some other "entry" (which also lost its original name). Reboot will fix this, unless your system is an old (or unusual) one that keeps these device files as static.

---

> Also what exactly is `/dev/sda`?

It is a special file that (usually) corresponds to your HDD or another storage. Unix identifies such resources by a major number and a minor number. Generally, the major number identifies the device driver and the minor number identifies a particular device (possibly out of many) that the driver controls. To see these numbers try `ls -l /dev/sda`. My output is:

> ```
> brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jul   8 00:48 /dev/sda
> ```

This `8, 0` fragment is a `<major>, <minor>` tuple here.

I wrote that `/dev/sda` *usually* corresponds to your HDD because in your case (after `mv`) you now have something else under this name.

> Is it the directory where the hard drive/SSD is mounted?

No. When you mount it the command is like

```
mount /dev/sda /a/directory/to/mount/to/
```

so these are two different things.

(Note it's usually `/dev/sda1` or so that is passed to a `mount` command, not `/dev/sda`. This is because `sda1` corresponds to a *partition* while `sda` corresponds to the *entire HDD*. Filesystems usually live inside partitions but it's possible to have one on a device where there are no partitions, so the above command may happen. Compare: *[Uses of single-partition disk configuration](https://superuser.com/q/1181320/432690)*).

Comment: Okay so '/dev/sda' is only a file which purpose is to give informations about the first SCSI/SATA disk [link] (http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki//dev) connected to the computer am I right ?

Comment: And I could have degraded the content of my drive only if I somehow managed to overwrite the directory my drive is mounted on with the file I 'mv'ed which is impossible(?). Anyway thank you for your reply and please apology my poor english but I'm not a native speaker :)

Comment: Oh and indeed, rebooting fixed the issue, almost forgot