# Assign a device filename by UUID?

Tags: linux, uuid

I have a system with multiple drives installed. I can see a list of all drives along with their UUIDs and labels using the blkid command (omitting some lines for conciseness):

```
root@ubuntu:~/avl# blkid
/dev/sdy1: UUID="F00D-78FA" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system" PARTUUID="23fc9408-58b2-4905-983e-be0a4dc4adee"
/dev/sdy2: UUID="0c58da23-7ef5-4177-807c-d9164174c092" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Linux filesystem" PARTUUID="81c156e7-1113-46b4-9365-ed3a262fc475"
/dev/sdd1: UUID="ff1954fe-e8c1-4253-abbc-24d3d6c6a6c5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="dae0a716-01"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="b26fadc6-cd26-4f2a-8a41-91238737ae4b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="48b181eb-01"
/dev/sdu1: UUID="b9fb58ab-474c-4113-9789-c3a02ed49ddf" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="51d5e885-01"
/dev/sda1: UUID="08e865f9-0b47-407d-b103-b93836479de4" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9bc2dad1-01"
```

You can see that my boot drive is assigned to `/dev/sdy`. However, I'd like for this drive to be assigned to `/dev/sda` instead.

My question is: Is there any way to force Linux to assign a drive with a given UUID to a given device filename?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)? Why should `/dev/sda` be better than `/dev/sdy`? If you need to reliably identify a certain disk/partition/filesystem then use `/dev/disk/by-id/` or `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` (read [this](https://superuser.com/q/1308888/432690)).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I wasn't aware of the `/dev/disk` directory -- thank you for bringing this magical directory to my attention! After thinking through my question more, what I am looking for is indeed a way to reliably refer to a drive (as in a real, physical drive that is plugged into my chassis)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, the "sd?" is assigned in the order in which they were detected by the OS.  This is usually in the order the BIOS puts them... and/or RAID controller... and/or device LUN... etc.

Without defining some `udev` rules to name them manually... you're going to have to change the order in which they were detected.