# Unable to create FAT32 on USB disk (bad number of FATs)

Tags: linux, usb

Being a beginner to Linux, I've been messing with the software while my USB is not showing up after I zeroed it with the terminal. I then ran the command for making file system, but it shows me this:

[image: mkfs.msdos]

In the settings app, this is how the USB disk shows up as:

[image: this]

Could anybody tell me what's the matter and how do I fix it? I want to make it ready to boot from it.

Comment: Why do you want to change the number of FATs?

Comment: @davidbaumann I'm no more than a newbie in Linux. I just found it on google, but I'm trying to get sense of all this. It'll take some time for me.

Comment: How did you zero it? Did you already set up a partition table?

Answer (score 2):

- You do not want `-f 32`. You probably want `-F 32`. See `man 8 mkfs.msdos` for details. Remember Linux is case-sensitive in general.
- You most likely should not create a filesystem on `/dev/sdb`. Create partition(s) first (with `fdisk`, `gdisk` or whatever), then create a filesystem on `/dev/sdb1`. Compare [*Uses of single-partition disk configuration*](https://superuser.com/q/1181320/432690).

Comment: For USB sticks it's not unusual to create a filesystem on whole disk... The GNOME Disks app shown in the screenshot could create a partition table as well, using "⋮" -> "Format Disk".

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax should be: `mkfs.msdos -F 32 /dev/sdb`

If you wanted to add a label, `mkfs.msdos -F 32 -n THISTHING /deb/sdb`

It is ideal to use all caps when naming FAT filesystems. However, it is uncommon to create a filesystem prior to making a table as the other answer has said. There are tools such as fatresize you can use to make separate partitions if you wanted to if you choose to create the partition table first. If you wanted instructions on that:

```
# parted -a optimal /dev/sdb # IF it is still /dev/sdb
    mktable msdos # msdos or gpt are options, I am assuming msdos because of your FAT selection
    mkpart # here you can choose anything for name and filesystem, 
           # it won't matter since you'll be making a new file system
```

When it prompts you for partition size, enter `-1` for the ending sector to get the partition to span the entire disk.

Then you will now have /dev/sdb1 to run `mkfs.msdos -F 32 /dev/sdb` on.

Note: if you wanted FAT for compatibility between operating systems, you should look into exFAT. It is similar to FAT, except there is no 4GB restriction. You may run into a 4GB filesize problem if customizing a Windows .wim or with media.