# Swap space not updated

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, swap, hotswapping

I just made my USB an additional swap and after all done I did not know how could I take the USB off my computer properly, so I just pulled it off. When I open `htop` the swap space that the USB provided stayed there and when I made another additional swap space with the same USB it got even bigger.

How do I update my swap space and how can I take the USB off properly?
Also is there a way to make the pendrive a storage thing again?

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: I answered both your questions, but next time please ask one question per post. Handling swap and wiping a device are two distinct subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the entire pendrive (e.g. `/dev/sdx`) was used as swap.

> How do I update my swap space and how can I take the USB off properly?

You enable/disable devices and files for paging and swapping with `swapon`/`swapoff`. I guess you had used `mkswap` and `swapon`. You should have run `swapoff /dev/sdx` before unplugging the device.

Now sole `swapon` probably shows something like `/dev/sdx (deleted)`. Unfortunately `swapoff /dev/sdx` will yield `No such file or directory`. I have found no way to overcome this (compare [this old topic](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0810.2/0459.html) and [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/668159)).

A reboot should solve the issue. In case you have added the now unwanted swap to your `/etc/fstab`, you probably want to remove the entry.

---

> Is there a way to make the pendrive a storage thing again?

To "clear" the pendrive use `wipefs`, e.g. `wipefs -a /dev/sdy`. Then there should be no problem with creating partitions (`fdisk`, `gdisk`, …) or a filesystem (`mkfs`, but mind [this](https://superuser.com/a/1181406/432690)).