# How to format usb stick to respond to bash mount script?

Tags: linux, bash, mount

using
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)

List all drives: UNmounted and mounted

`lsblk --noheadings --raw | awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}' | uniq -c | grep 1 | awk '{print "/dev/"$2}' ;`

/dev/loop
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda5
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdb1
/dev/sdc
/dev/sdd
/dev/sdd1

From above bash, we have 2 usb sticks c and d as:
`/dev/sdc`  FAT (32-bit version)
`/dev/sdd`
`/dev/sdd1` FAT (32-bit version)

How come sdd has 2 entries?
`/dev/sdd`
`/dev/sdd1` FAT (32-bit version)

How to format usb `sdc` to get 2 entries like `sdd` above?

Why?

Because it seems that 2 entries behaves better for
UNmounting usb manually via DISKs and
mounting usb via a bash script below.

Show UNmounted drives and Show Extended Partition Types:

`lsblk --noheadings --raw -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk '$1~/[[:digit:]]/ && $2 == ""' ;`

Show stats:  UNmounted drives and Extended Partition Type:

`lsblk --noheadings --raw | awk '$1~/s.*[[:digit:]]/ && $7==""' ;`

Mount drives via bash.   Then do virus scanning:
`lsblk  --noheadings --raw | awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}' | uniq -c | grep 1 | awk '{print "/dev/"$2}' | grep -E "(/dev/sd.)[[:digit:]]" | xargs -I{} -n1 udisksctl mount -b {} ;`

`Mounted /dev/sdd1 at /media/u3/USBstick`

`/dev/sdc`  FAT (32-bit version)
is manually UNmounted and
above bash script does not mount `/dev/sdc`

`/dev/sdd`
`/dev/sdd1 FAT (32-bit version)`
is manually UNmounted and
above bash script works.
Mounts `sdd`

Target is to have bash script
mount all drives before a virus scan.

Explain.
Why `sdc` is only `1` entry versus `2` for `sdd`?
`/dev/sdc` FAT (32-bit version)
`/dev/sdd`
`/dev/sdd1` FAT (32-bit version)

Explain.
How to format `sdc`?
So `sdc` responds to above bash mount script
like `sdd` responds.

--

Comment: `sdd` is a whole block device. `sdd1` is the first partition within the device. See a table in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705262/108618). A setup where there is no partition table and a filesystem takes the whole device is called "superfloppy". See this question: [Uses of single-partition disk configuration](https://superuser.com/q/1181320/432690). The fact you and your script are confused kinda confirms what I said in my answer there.

Comment: 1. Formatting usb by DISKs results in unwanted 'superfloppy' ```sdc``` meaning ```sdc1``` is absent .  2. Format usb by ```sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdc``` results with message ```mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)```  and  
```mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdc: No medium found```.   How to format usb?  to reach the target  ```sdc``` with ```sdc1```  being the first partition within the device. i understand 'Programs may expect a partition table first, a filesystem later.'  i understand this means the mount script expects ```sdc``` with partition ```sdc1``` .

Comment: FYI: `$ lsblk  -o PATH` replaces most parts of your initial thing ending in "awk".

Comment: Hi Hannu, ```$ lsblk  -o PATH``` works, meaning, List all drives: UNmounted and mounted, but 16 items were Listed and are of no interest, being ```/dev/loop0``` to ```/dev/loop15``` .  The first script of 102 characters shortens uninteresting data to 1 item ```/dev/loop```.   i read ```/dev/loopX``` are virtual devices, read only, connected to the snapd service, extra loop devices added for every software you install using "snap" and  ```/dev/loopX``` can be removed by uninstalling the app via snapd.  Any ideas how to format usb?  to get ```sdc``` and ```sdc1``` .