# mounted disk space is not getting used automatically

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk-space, ubuntu-20.04

HI I have attached a volume of 1TB to my Ubuntu server.

I can see the mounted disk in `df -h`.

```
/dev/vdb 1000G 1.1G 999G 1% /data
```

Note: `/dev/vdb` is the new mounted disk.

If I do `fdisk -l`, the error `Partition table entries are not in disk order` is coming. Below is the output.

```
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Disk /dev/vdb: 1000 GiB, 1073743044608 bytes, 2097154384 sectors 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

So, what might be wrong here. How do I fix this?

Actually due to this, the extended disk space is not being used or consumed.

I have checked many blogs and all I saw is `fdisk /dev/vdb` which gives option to fix the partition order. I tried it and below output came.

```
Nothing to do. Ordering is correct already. Failed to fix partitions order
```

Comment: How do you define "automatically" and how did you inform your operating system of your personal concept of "automatically"?

Answer (score 2):

You truncated the output of `fdisk -l`. `Partition table entries are not in disk order` appearing before `Disk /dev/vdb: …` refers to the device *preceding* `/dev/vdb` in the output of `fdisk -l`. It does not refer to `/dev/vdb`.

The output you have shown for `/dev/vdb` lists no partition table (and thus no partitions).

If `df` shows you `/dev/vdb` then `/dev/vdb` is mounted. If it's mounted then it contains a filesystem (you really mount a filesystem, not a device/partition). If it contains a filesystem then it doesn't need a partition table.

Somewhat related: [*Uses of single-partition disk configuration*](https://superuser.com/q/1181320/432690).

Everything seems fine with `/dev/vdb`. The output of `df -h` you posted indicates you now have `999G` available (i.e. free space) in `/data`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the output of `df`, your disk is connected, mounted and works as expected. You might want to make use of it by writing data to the directory where you mounted it, in this case `/data`