# mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount

I want to mount a hard disk in remote debian server to retrieve some important data. The `fdisk -l` info of the disk :

> ```
> Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> Disklabel type: dos
> Disk identifier: 0xd603e167
>
> Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
> /dev/sdc1        2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G  6 FAT16
> ```

But when I try to mount it:

```
mount  /dev/sdc1 /back
```

I get this error:

> ```
> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
>        missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>
>        In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>        dmesg | tail or so.
> ```

I have also tried

```
mount -t vfat  /dev/sdc1 /back
```

and

```
mount -t ext4  /dev/sdc1 /back
```

But they all give the same error.

Also,

```
fsck /dev/sdc1
```

yields:

> ```
> fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
> e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
> ext2fs_check_desc: Corrupt group descriptor: bad block for block bitmap
> fsck.ext4: Group descriptors look bad... trying backup blocks...
> The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 244190208 blocks
> The physical size of the device is 244189952 blocks
> Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
> Abort<y>?
> ```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What filesystem do you expect to be there? Did you check syslog as advised? What did it say? Unlikely, but not impossible: [this scenario](https://superuser.com/a/1146202/432690); so you should try `mount -o ro /dev/sdc /back` (note: `sdc`, not `sdc1`) and see what happens. Eventually you can examine the disk with `testdisk`, maybe this tool will find a filesystem somewhere.

Comment: The filesystem that `fdisk -l` shows is `FAT16`.  But I guess it should have been ext4, as it was formatted by Linux before. The syslog says: `kernel: [24459.809995] EXT4-fs (sdc1): bad geometry: block count 244190208 exceeds size of device (244189952 blocks)
`

Comment: I wouldn't pay much attention to this `FAT16` because `mount` in Linux never does. The partition table is (should be) outside of any partition; when you pass `/dev/sdc1` as an argument to `mount`, it doesn't open `/dev/sdc` to check the partition type.