# Mount virtual vfat drive to raspberry pi

Tags: linux, debian, mount, raspberry-pi, virtual-drive

I'm trying to mount virtual vfat drive to Raspberry Pi. This solution was working then we formatted the vritual vfat drive via USB OTG, now  I cannot mount the drive back to pi but I can still mount it to another USB device.

Here is the configuration.

Run only once for configuration

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dir/to/data/data.bin bs=512 count=7680000
mkdosfs /dir/to/data/data.bin
kpartx -a /dir/to/data/data.bin
```

Run on every boot after initial configuration

```
kpartx -a /dir/to/data/data.bin
```

The rest commands are executed by a OTG USB management application

To mount to itself

```
mount -o rw,umask=0000 -t vfat /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/data
```

Unmount from itself

```
umount /mnt/data
```

Mount to USB

```
modprobe g_mass_storage file=/dir/to/data/data.bin stall=0
```

Unmount from USB

```
modprobe g_mass_storage file=/dir/to/data/data.bin stall=0
```

When the vfat virtual disk was mounted to USB OTG we formatted it from the device it was connected to it to see what would happen.

And now we can't mount the virtual drive back to itself. Even after deleting the Virtual drive and rebuilding it.

```
mount -o rw,umask=0000 -t vfat /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/data
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/loop0p1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

or

```
mount -o rw,umask=0000 -t vfat /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/data
mount: special device /dev/mapper/loop0p1 does not exist
```

What I have tried

```
modprobe -r g_mass_storage //Unmount from usb
umount /mnt/data //Unmount from itself
kpartx -dv /dir/to/data.bin //unmap virtual drive
rm /dir/to/data.bin //delete the virtual file system
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dir/to/data.bin bs=512 count=7680000 //Create a new virtual drive
mkdosfs /dir/to/data/data.bin //Format to vfat
kpartx -av /dir/to/data.bin //Map to dev
mount -o rw,umask=0000 -t vfat /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/data //Mount to itself
```

Still getting one of the two error messages but I can still Mount it to the USB and read it as a fat drive with Windows 10

We are running Raspbian(Debian based)

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command

```
mkdosfs /dir/to/data/data.bin
```

creates a filesystem on the *entire* "device" `data.bin`. There's no partition table within it. Such setup is called superfloppy. My general opinion is [it should be avoided](https://superuser.com/a/1181406/432690), unless you know possible pitfalls and accept them.

I expect Windows to keep it this way while it formats a superfloppy shared via `g_mass_storage` module.

There's no partition table so `kpartx` is unnecessary. **You should mount the entire file.** Modern `mount` implementations should associate a loop device automatically:

```
mount -o rw,umask=0000 -t vfat /dir/to/data/data.bin /mnt/data
```

(If your `mount` doesn't, use `losetup` or even `kpartx`. But the resulting device will be like `loop0`, e.g. `/dev/loop0`; mount this one, not `loop0p1`).

I'm surprised `mount ... /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/data` worked when you run it for the first time. It's fishy. From the very beginning you should mount the entire file because `mkdosfs` operated on the entire file.

---

I believe I addressed the root issue. The below explanation of what happened next may be totally wrong.

Note this kind of issue is possible: [*Windows does not mount USB NTFS superfloppy*](https://superuser.com/q/1060252/432690). In your case it's FAT32 superfloppy and while Windows seems to have no problem with it, `kpartx` may.

This is because [FAT32 boot record](https://www.easeus.com/resource/fat32-disk-structure.htm) stores executable code where a partition table in MBR would be. This code may be anything. You run `kpartx` and it expects MBR with a valid partition table. Instead it gets FAT32 boot record. Then:

- either it doesn't find anything like partition table so `special device /dev/mapper/loop0p1 does not exist` afterwards;
- or it finds a semi-valid one, creates `/dev/mapper/loop0p1` (and maybe `loop0p2` etc.) that points to some part of your file, but since the filesystem is on the entire file, this "partition" makes no sense, has `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock`.

The story is similar to [my answer to the already linked question](https://superuser.com/a/1146202/432690). I guess in your case it's `kpartx` that gets confused.

---

If you have created a partition table inside the file (e.g. with `fdisk data.bin`), defined one or more partitions, run `kpartx -a ...` and created a filesystem on `/dev/mapper/loop0p1` -- then you should mount it like `mount ... /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/data`.

I think in this case you could run `modprobe g_mass_storage`

- either with `file=/dir/to/data/data.bin` and Windows would see the entire "device" with its partition table;
- or with `file=/dev/mapper/loop0p1` and Windows would see a "device" that is a superfloppy.